# "DxvkMemoryAllocator: Memory allocation failed" while running any WineHQ dxvk (d3d) game

Tags: memory, swap, wine, crash

While running any game, that is too memory hungry, thru Wine (WineHQ) it may completely fill up the RAM memory, before it have time to swap anything, causing this error:
"DxvkMemoryAllocator: Memory allocation failed"

Is there some way to prevent that?

I read (need to find the link about it) that it cant be fixed in dxvk...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encounter this message, there are actually two possibilities:

## You memory is too small. You need to reserve some space for DXVK

This usually happens if you find sys mem is filled up with used + buffer + cache on crash.

Run this command to ensure there are always 1GB free space for DXVK:

```
echo $(( 1024 * 1024 )) | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes
```

## The application is 32-bit, and wine by default only allocates in a 2GB space

This usually happens when you find your PC have free memory, but the application still crashes.

You need to edit launch options to add `WINE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE=1` or `PROTON_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE=1` to allow wine to allocate in 2GB - 4GB space.

Comment: thx, I will research how `min_free_kbytes` works exacly, because I tried that setting and I just saw like the memory went vanishing (not exactly t hat) and the loop I created to stress the memory temporary just got activated more often. I am scared of disabling that loop as it may "freeze" (temporarily about 10 to 15 minutes) my machine and I will have to reboot forcedly.

Answer (score 0):

well, the way I am workarounding it is to run this:
`stress-ng --vm-bytes 5000M --timeout 15 --vm-keep --vm 1 --verbose`
as I have only 6GB of RAM.

but before, it is good to SIGSTOP the wine game, and also any other memory hungry app like chromium.

that command will force many things on RAM to be moved to the swap, and in that way, the dxvk error wont happen.

before doing that, wine was filling up almost 99% of the RAM if not 100%...

it has to be repeated everytime RAM usage is too high, so better script it :)

Comment: It would be a good idea to file a bug report for this ; RAM fragmentation is a big deal when it comes to games and Vulkan.

Comment: @Paradox There are many ppl complaining about that error, but not on stackexchange that I could find. I dont get it, shouldnt normal swapping happen before dxvk error have a chance to happen? using stress-ng is only a way to making swapping happens in a better way. So, may be better swapping configuration could be a better workaround. I have no idea if it happens on windows, so you think this is a Wine DXVK problem only?

Comment: IMHO, it seems like the usual RAM fragmentation issue encountered with Vulkan associated with a non-swapping bug. Whether it's a DXVK, Wine, Linux kernel, or even a Windows problem as well, I would just file a bug report so this is redirected if necessary, and addressed in the end. Keep in mind that DXVK can have a slight to moderate overhead, so this is problem where I would start poking. This is as far as I can tell without a log and further research on the subject.

Comment: "non-swapping bug" yep, it appears to be that indeed, so my guess would be 2 bug reports, one for kernel (this swap bug) and another for wine/dxvk (trying to allocate more than there is available RAM) right? I dont really know how this works specifically, so these are just my guesses. My idea was to provide a workaround with this answer not a fix, but of course a fix is the right thing, thats why I didnt accept my own answer :)